# How can I add a shape to a text caption?

Tags: r, ggplot2, caption

I have a dataset "datanishatlong". I am trying to make a plot using ggplot2. I am running this code in R.

```
library(ggplot)
mycolor <- c("firebrick", "green")
intervention_labels <- c("Control", "Case")
xlab <- c("Baseline", "Week 1", "Week 2", "Week 3", "Week 4", "End")
ggplot(datanishatlong, aes(x=time, y=vas, color = intervention)) + 
  geom_point(position = position_jitterdodge(dodge.width = 0.8, jitter.height = 0.2, jitter.width = 0.2), alpha = 0.5, size = 2) + 
  geom_point(stat = "summary", fun = "mean", size = 4, shape = 22, position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), alpha = 0.5, show.legend = F, fill = "orange") + 
  scale_color_manual(values = mycolor, labels = intervention_labels) + 
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x="Time", y="VAS", title = "VAS across follow-up times", color = "Intervention", caption = "Squares represent mean value") +
  theme(plot.caption = element_text(size=6, color="orange", face="italic")) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = xlab)
```

I want to add the shape of the second geom_point() [i.e., an orange square] to the caption of the plot. Specifically I want it to appear just before the caption text.

Here is the dataset.

```
sno,time,intervention,vas
1,At Baseline,Case,7
1,At 1 week,Case,6
1,At 2 weeks,Case,5
1,At 3 weeks,Case,4
1,At 4 weeks,Case,4
1,At end of Follow-up,Case,4
2,At Baseline,Case,7
2,At 1 week,Case,6
2,At 2 weeks,Case,5
2,At 3 weeks,Case,5
2,At 4 weeks,Case,4
2,At end of Follow-up,Case,3
3,At Baseline,Case,8
3,At 1 week,Case,7
3,At 2 weeks,Case,7
3,At 3 weeks,Case,6
3,At 4 weeks,Case,5
3,At end of Follow-up,Case,5
4,At Baseline,Case,7
4,At 1 week,Case,6
4,At 2 weeks,Case,5
4,At 3 weeks,Case,4
4,At 4 weeks,Case,4
4,At end of Follow-up,Case,4
5,At Baseline,Case,8
5,At 1 week,Case,7
5,At 2 weeks,Case,7
5,At 3 weeks,Case,6
5,At 4 weeks,Case,4
5,At end of Follow-up,Case,5
6,At Baseline,Case,7
6,At 1 week,Case,6
6,At 2 weeks,Case,5
6,At 3 weeks,Case,4
6,At 4 weeks,Case,3
6,At end of Follow-up,Case,4
7,At Baseline,Case,7
7,At 1 week,Case,6
7,At 2 weeks,Case,5
7,At 3 weeks,Case,4
7,At 4 weeks,Case,4
7,At end of Follow-up,Case,4
8,At Baseline,Case,8
8,At 1 week,Case,8
8,At 2 weeks,Case,7
8,At 3 weeks,Case,7
8,At 4 weeks,Case,5
8,At end of Follow-up,Case,4
9,At Baseline,Case,7
9,At 1 week,Case,6
9,At 2 weeks,Case,6
9,At 3 weeks,Case,5
9,At 4 weeks,Case,4
9,At end of Follow-up,Case,4
10,At Baseline,Case,7
10,At 1 week,Case,7
10,At 2 weeks,Case,6
10,At 3 weeks,Case,5
10,At 4 weeks,Case,5
10,At end of Follow-up,Case,4
11,At Baseline,Case,8
11,At 1 week,Case,7
11,At 2 weeks,Case,6
11,At 3 weeks,Case,7
11,At 4 weeks,Case,5
11,At end of Follow-up,Case,5
12,At Baseline,Case,8
12,At 1 week,Case,7
12,At 2 weeks,Case,7
12,At 3 weeks,Case,5
12,At 4 weeks,Case,4
12,At end of Follow-up,Case,5
13,At Baseline,Case,8
13,At 1 week,Case,6
13,At 2 weeks,Case,7
13,At 3 weeks,Case,6
13,At 4 weeks,Case,4
13,At end of Follow-up,Case,5
14,At Baseline,Case,7
14,At 1 week,Case,7
14,At 2 weeks,Case,6
14,At 3 weeks,Case,6
14,At 4 weeks,Case,5
14,At end of Follow-up,Case,4
15,At Baseline,Case,7
15,At 1 week,Case,6
15,At 2 weeks,Case,6
15,At 3 weeks,Case,5
15,At 4 weeks,Case,4
15,At end of Follow-up,Case,5
16,At Baseline,Case,7
16,At 1 week,Case,6
16,At 2 weeks,Case,6
16,At 3 weeks,Case,5
16,At 4 weeks,Case,4
16,At end of Follow-up,Case,4
17,At Baseline,Case,7
17,At 1 week,Case,6
17,At 2 weeks,Case,5
17,At 3 weeks,Case,4
17,At 4 weeks,Case,4
17,At end of Follow-up,Case,4
18,At Baseline,Case,6
18,At 1 week,Case,6
18,At 2 weeks,Case,5
18,At 3 weeks,Case,4
18,At 4 weeks,Case,3
18,At end of Follow-up,Case,3
19,At Baseline,Case,8
19,At 1 week,Case,7
19,At 2 weeks,Case,7
19,At 3 weeks,Case,6
19,At 4 weeks,Case,5
19,At end of Follow-up,Case,4
20,At Baseline,Case,7
20,At 1 week,Case,7
20,At 2 weeks,Case,5
20,At 3 weeks,Case,4
20,At 4 weeks,Case,4
20,At end of Follow-up,Case,3
21,At Baseline,Control,7
21,At 1 week,Control,7
21,At 2 weeks,Control,6
21,At 3 weeks,Control,5
21,At 4 weeks,Control,4
21,At end of Follow-up,Control,5
22,At Baseline,Control,8
22,At 1 week,Control,7
22,At 2 weeks,Control,6
22,At 3 weeks,Control,5
22,At 4 weeks,Control,5
22,At end of Follow-up,Control,5
23,At Baseline,Control,7
23,At 1 week,Control,6
23,At 2 weeks,Control,5
23,At 3 weeks,Control,5
23,At 4 weeks,Control,3
23,At end of Follow-up,Control,4
24,At Baseline,Control,7
24,At 1 week,Control,6
24,At 2 weeks,Control,5
24,At 3 weeks,Control,5
24,At 4 weeks,Control,4
24,At end of Follow-up,Control,5
25,At Baseline,Control,7
25,At 1 week,Control,6
25,At 2 weeks,Control,6
25,At 3 weeks,Control,6
25,At 4 weeks,Control,5
25,At end of Follow-up,Control,4
26,At Baseline,Control,8
26,At 1 week,Control,7
26,At 2 weeks,Control,6
26,At 3 weeks,Control,6
26,At 4 weeks,Control,6
26,At end of Follow-up,Control,5
27,At Baseline,Control,8
27,At 1 week,Control,7
27,At 2 weeks,Control,6
27,At 3 weeks,Control,6
27,At 4 weeks,Control,5
27,At end of Follow-up,Control,6
28,At Baseline,Control,7
28,At 1 week,Control,6
28,At 2 weeks,Control,5
28,At 3 weeks,Control,4
28,At 4 weeks,Control,4
28,At end of Follow-up,Control,3
29,At Baseline,Control,7
29,At 1 week,Control,8
29,At 2 weeks,Control,7
29,At 3 weeks,Control,7
29,At 4 weeks,Control,6
29,At end of Follow-up,Control,5
30,At Baseline,Control,8
30,At 1 week,Control,7
30,At 2 weeks,Control,6
30,At 3 weeks,Control,5
30,At 4 weeks,Control,4
30,At end of Follow-up,Control,6
31,At Baseline,Control,7
31,At 1 week,Control,6
31,At 2 weeks,Control,6
31,At 3 weeks,Control,6
31,At 4 weeks,Control,5
31,At end of Follow-up,Control,6
32,At Baseline,Control,7
32,At 1 week,Control,6
32,At 2 weeks,Control,6
32,At 3 weeks,Control,5
32,At 4 weeks,Control,4
32,At end of Follow-up,Control,5
33,At Baseline,Control,8
33,At 1 week,Control,7
33,At 2 weeks,Control,7
33,At 3 weeks,Control,6
33,At 4 weeks,Control,6
33,At end of Follow-up,Control,7
34,At Baseline,Control,7
34,At 1 week,Control,6
34,At 2 weeks,Control,5
34,At 3 weeks,Control,5
34,At 4 weeks,Control,4
34,At end of Follow-up,Control,4
35,At Baseline,Control,7
35,At 1 week,Control,6
35,At 2 weeks,Control,7
35,At 3 weeks,Control,6
35,At 4 weeks,Control,5
35,At end of Follow-up,Control,6
36,At Baseline,Control,6
36,At 1 week,Control,5
36,At 2 weeks,Control,6
36,At 3 weeks,Control,5
36,At 4 weeks,Control,4
36,At end of Follow-up,Control,3
37,At Baseline,Control,8
37,At 1 week,Control,7
37,At 2 weeks,Control,7
37,At 3 weeks,Control,6
37,At 4 weeks,Control,5
37,At end of Follow-up,Control,6
38,At Baseline,Control,7
38,At 1 week,Control,6
38,At 2 weeks,Control,6
38,At 3 weeks,Control,5
38,At 4 weeks,Control,4
38,At end of Follow-up,Control,5
39,At Baseline,Control,7
39,At 1 week,Control,5
39,At 2 weeks,Control,5
39,At 3 weeks,Control,4
39,At 4 weeks,Control,5
39,At end of Follow-up,Control,5
40,At Baseline,Control,7
40,At 1 week,Control,6
40,At 2 weeks,Control,5
40,At 3 weeks,Control,5
40,At 4 weeks,Control,4
40,At end of Follow-up,Control,5
```

I couldn't get an orange square just before the caption text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do this using `ggtext` and Unicode symbol 25A0:

```r
library(ggtext)

ggplot(datanishatlong, aes(time, vas, color = intervention)) + 
  geom_point(position = position_jitterdodge(dodge.width = 0.8, 
                                             jitter.height = 0.2, 
                                             jitter.width = 0.2), 
             alpha = 0.5, size = 2) + 
  geom_point(stat = "summary", fun = "mean", size = 4, shape = 22, 
             position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), alpha = 0.5, 
             fill = "orange", show.legend = FALSE) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = mycolor, labels = intervention_labels) + 
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x="Time", y="VAS", title = "VAS across follow-up times", 
       color = "Intervention",
       caption = paste0("<span style = 'color:#FF800080;font-size:20pt'>\u25A0",
                        "</span>  <i>Squares represent mean value")) +
  theme(plot.caption = element_markdown()) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = xlab)
```

[image]

Comment: You're welcome @haqinaam . Very nice first question, by the way.